# help me to display featured image of specific post by post id

Tags: custom-post-types

i need to attach an image from a specific post by using post id of custom post type which i created new...
how can i..? 
actually i created a new 5 post type named 'flips'... and meta content areas are website, title back, content back, main title, thumbnail etc.,.

```
<?php $mypost = get_post(28); echo apply_filters('the_content',$mypost->post_content); ?>
<?php $mypost = get_post(28);
echo apply_filters('website',$mypost->website);
echo apply_filters('titleback',$mypost->titleback);
echo apply_filters('contentback',$mypost->contentback);
?>
```

i need to add post thumbnail to display here also how can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) like this:

```
<?php $mypost = get_post(28); echo apply_filters('the_content',$mypost->post_content); ?>
<?php $mypost = get_post(28);
echo apply_filters('website',$mypost->website);
echo apply_filters('titleback',$mypost->titleback);
echo apply_filters('contentback',$mypost->contentback);

echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypost->ID, 'thumbnail');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

thnx alot.., 
and i got another good method for this.., but there face a problem that ,how can is show contents of the newly created custom meta content add area sections in my custom post type named 'flips',
here i craeted new 3 sections to add more contents, that are, website, titleback, contentback, shows in above my quistion also..,

'flips','p' => 28 ) );?>
have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

....
....here i need contents of newly added meta content arears... 
....

help me plss..,
also suggest me any other better code for this..?
help me plss..sir.,